# Videogular CSS not working - UI distorted

Tags: css, html, video, videogular

I am using Videogular, it is absolutely good there is no doubt about that but works only with http:/ calls as its theme is in http://www.videogular.com/styles/themes/default/latest/videogular.css.
But my application work only on secure https. Problem with http and https cross calls. So i decided to download the content of videogular css and try to implement manually. But it seems it doesnt work. 
Can any one help please?
either by letting me know how to integrate videogular css manually to project or if there is any https support available from videogular.

Comment: Got the answer from Videogular guys
https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular/issues/175

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still haven't solved this problem...
Can you be more specific? 
the only thing that you need to do is to import the css from your server like(using relative path):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/yourpathtocss/css/videogular.css">
```

and make sure that you can access this resource. Them you need to make a div with class:videogular-container and put the videogular tags inside like:

```
<div ng-controller="YourCtrl as controller" class="videogular-container">
<videogular vg-theme="controller.config.theme.url">
    <vg-media vg-src="controller.config.source"> </vg-media>
</videogular>
```